# issue with importing tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-import, importerror, python-importlib

I have an issue with importing tensorflow , i used to use tensorflow 2.10 and i upgraded it to 2.16 to use keras-nlp and keras 3 and other new features , but now i want to import tensorflow but nothing of it will be imported , if i run
`import tensorflow as tf` it will be okay but if i run `print(tf.__version__)` or any other commands , it would return

```
module tensorflow has no attribute __version__
```

or ... ;

also when i print `print(tf)` , it will return

```
<module 'tensorflow' (<_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader object at 0x0000015D51B86B00>)>
```

what is the problem ? it has been fully downloaded and when i run " pip install tensorflow " , all the dependencies are satisfied and it is tensorflow 2.16

Comment: Kinda brute-force and broad, but did you try `pip3 install --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir tensorflow`? This forces to reinstall, and also disables the cache and re-downloads all packages. If your error comes from a broken installation, this should fix it.